# Getting Object properties for an object loaded in a canvas

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, mesh

I have loaded an object from an object file into the scene. 
I perform some transformation, manipulation on it.
How can I retrieve the new information of the object?
E.g.:all vertices new location after a rotation operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use glGetDoublev with GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX to get the model-view matrix after applying your transformations.